# How to set the caret to a specific position in etherpad?

Tags: etherpad

I'm authoring a plugin and on some operations of the plugin, the caret moves back to 0:0. I can get the caret position with

```
exports.aceKeyEvent = function(hook_name, args, cb) {
        line = args.editorInfo.ace_caretLine();
        char = args.editorInfo.ace_caretColumn();
}
```

.. but so far I didn't find anything to set the caret. There suppose to be a Set selection method, but the documentation is not giving me any hints.

Comment: Etherpad / the ace editor creates an iframe containing a document with the tag:
`<body contenteditable="true">` maybe it would be enough to set the caret within standard html operations / javascript.

Comment: I got a hint that [ep_citation](https://github.com/JohnMcLear/ep_citation/blob/master/static/js/index.js#L175) is doing the job on that line, ...

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to John Mc Lear, the solution came up. [example](https://github.com/JohnMcLear/ep_citation/blob/master/static/js/index.js#L175)

Only after a call to *ace_replaceRange* will a call to *ace_performSelectionChange* set the caret position in an acekeyEvent hook, where we get the ace object with ace_callWithAce.

However, this works in a postAceInit hook.

```
        context.ace.callWithAce(function(ace) {
            ace.ace_performSelectionChange([line - 1, char], [line - 1, char], false);
        }, 'padsearch_callstack', true);
```